# How to flatten a list containing both strings and lists-of-strings?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, flatten

How best to flatten an `ArrayList<Object>` which contains both `ArrayList<String>` and `String` objects into a flat `ArrayList<String>`?

**Example**

Input: `[item1, item2, item3, [item4a, item4b, item4c]]`

Expected output: `[item1, item2, item3, item4a, item4b, item4c]`

Code to create dummy example:

```
ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
objectList.add("item1");
objectList.add("item2");
objectList.add("item3");

ArrayList<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();
subList.add("item4a");
subList.add("item4b");
subList.add("item4c");

objectList.add(subList);
```

**(Not) working solution**

```
private ArrayList<String> flattenList(ArrayList<Object> objectList) {
    ArrayList<String> flatLst = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    for (Object item :  objectList) {
        if (item.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {
            System.out.println(item);
            for (Object s : item) {
                flatLst.add(String.valueOf(s));
            }
        } else if (item.getClass() == String.class) {
            flatLst.add(String.valueOf(item));
        }
    }
    return flatLst;
}
```

This is giving the following error.

```
|               for (Object s : item) {
for-each not applicable to expression type
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    java.lang.Object
```

**Question**: How to fix this? Or perhaps better, what's a cleaner way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
objectList.add("item1");
objectList.add("item2");
objectList.add("item3");

ArrayList<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();
subList.add("item4a");
subList.add("item4b");
subList.add("item4c");

objectList.add(subList);
List<Object> flat = objectList.stream()
                              .map(obj -> (obj instanceof List) ? (List<Object>) obj : List.of(obj))
                              .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(flat);
```

Above code prints...

```
[item1, item2, item3, item4a, item4b, item4c]
```

### EDIT

As requested. `List<String>` instead of `List<Object>`

```java
List<String> flat = objectList.stream()
                              .map(obj -> (obj instanceof List) ? (List<Object>) obj : List.of(obj))
                              .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                              .map(obj -> String.valueOf(obj))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. How to have it return a `List<String>` instead of `List<Object>`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to help the compiler by casting the item like this:

```
for (Object s : (List) item) {
```

---

Or if you want an elegant solution, you can use streams as this:

```
private ArrayList<String> flattenList(ArrayList<Object> objectList) {
    return objectList.stream()
            .flatMap(this::extract)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

}

private Stream<String> extract(Object item) {
    if (item.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {
        return ((List<String>) item).stream();
    } else if (item.getClass() == String.class) {
        return Stream.of((String) item);
    }
    return Stream.empty();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However I'm getting the error `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: What did you mean @Andy? Which solution cause this problem?

Comment: I'm not so sure what the exact issue was here, when I tried to compile I would get the above error. Thanks for your help! I awarded to @Abra for conciseness

Answer (score 1):

For-each loops require either arrays or an instance of `Iterable` as their right-hand operand. The type of `item` is `Object`, so you need to cast it first.

```
if (item.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {
        ArrayList list = (ArrayList) item;
        for (Object s : list) {
            flatLst.add(String.valueOf(s));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing same thing if you must do it using loop. If you can use java8 than solution by [YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64856665/2106815) is better.

```
public static ArrayList<String> flattenList(ArrayList<Object> objectList) {
        ArrayList<String> flatLst = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for (Object item :  objectList) {
            if (item instanceof List) {
                System.out.println(item);
                for (Object s : (List)item) {
                    flatLst.add(String.valueOf(s));
                }
            } else if (item instanceof String ) {
                flatLst.add(String.valueOf(item));
            }
        }
        return flatLst;
    }
```